# Ethernet cable issue

Tags: networking, ethernet, cat6, cabling

Need some wisdom! Recently refurbished my house, so took advantage of the building work to lay cat 6 cables everywhere. Before all the work was completed I tested the each cable and they were all fine, this was a few months back. I also laid a cable to my back office.

Today I decided to set the office up and connect my PC. The PC wasn't picking up anything from the cable so I took out my ethernet tester and the strangest thing happened, on one end of the cable the lights 1-8 come up fine, the other end the lights 5-8 only come up.

I have put new connector and recrimped both ends but to no difference. Even if I switch the testers around, the same thing happens, the main tester shows 1-8 working and the smaller part shows 5-8. I am absolutely stumped at what the issue is??!

I have attached youtube video to give a better idea. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

https://youtu.be/ZepntB63S_g

https://youtu.be/ScU7Mb5w3qk

Comment: I used to have a tester similar to yours, does this one have a GND button on the end with a battery? Can you take a picture of the crimps with tab up, back lit with a flashlight? When your ran the wire did you staple it inside the wall? As it is this question will most likely be closed as "too broad". Please add any additional information that you can to the question. **Please don't respond in the comments section**